# Laravel authorize() assigns unexpected object to response

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-authorization

I have three Eloquent models for a recipe management application where `User` has many `cookbook`, `cookbook` has many `recipes` and so on (see below).

To authorize I'm using this policy:

```php
public function view(User $user, Recipes $recipe) {
    return $user->id === $recipe->cookbook->user_id;
}
```

Here is the controller:

```php
public function show($id) {
    $recipe = Recipes::find($id);
    $this->authorize('view', $recipe);

    return $recipe;
}
```

Testing this works fine, however I'm getting extra information in my response.

[image: Unexpected Result]

[image: Expected Result]

The response somehow gets assigned an extra object `cookbook`. After print testing the problem seems to lie on the line `$recipe->cookbook->user_id;` where if removed the result came to be as expected.

Am I overlooking something?

#### Models for Reference

##### `User`

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function cookbooks() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cookbook');
    }

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Recipes', 'App\Models\Cookbook');
    }
}
```

##### `Cookbook`

```php
class Cookbook extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['user_id'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'cookbook_name',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'cookbook_shared_user' => 'string'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Recipes');
    }
}
```

##### `Recipe`

```php
class Recipes extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['cookbook_id'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'recipe_name',
        'recipe_description',
        'recipe_video_url',
        'recipe_image_url'
    ];

    public function cookbook() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Cookbook');
    }
}
```

Comment: As @juaneizmendi said, you are loading the relationship (and holding it in `->cookbook`) when you do `$recipe->cookbook`. The best thing you can do is **NEVER** return a model if you don't want specific fields to be returned. In that case the **BEST** (and I would say **ONLY**, but that depends in what layer you are doing what) solution is to use [`API Resources`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources). This will be understood by any developer, any other solution could be more complex or non _Laravel-way_, hence more difficult to know/understand, so not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the relationship in your `policy`, exactly where you said:

```
$recipe->cookbook
```

Now in your controller, you can change your return to:

```
return $recipe->setAppends([]);
```

That will remove your appends like `cookbook`.

If you want more control you can use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction) (Laravel way).

Comment: I **strongly** suggest to use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources) than doing `$recipe->setAppends([]);`, it is the Laravel way and everybody will know what is happening in the code.

Comment: Thanks! this solution seems to do the trick for me.  The way I understand it, resources are used to transform/ format API responses.  Is it a good practice to create a resource for every API response or are there cases where you use for some and not the rest?